# YouTube API minimum embed size changed?

Tags: youtube-api

All the docs I've seen say that the minimum player size is 200x200, but when I attempt to embed http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=RByVyVvMpQI I get the following message in the Flash Player log:

```
info Error: player size set to 300x220 which is below minimum dimensions 320x60
```

Have the requirements changed?  Is it possible for the video owner to set a minimum?  WTF?

Answer (score 0):

In the youtube api documentation it is mentioned as.

> To allow room for critical player functionality, players must be at least 200px by 200px.

But in the JavaScript player documentation it is mentioned that the minimum player size varies with the Video quality.

> ```
> Quality level small: Player height is 240px, and player dimensions are at least 320px by 240px for 4:3 aspect ratio.
> Quality level medium: Player height is 360px, and player dimensions are 640px by 360px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) or 480px by 360px (for 4:3 aspect ratio).
> Quality level large: Player height is 480px, and player dimensions are 853px by 480px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) or 640px by 480px (for 4:3 aspect ratio).
> Quality level hd720: Player height is 720px, and player dimensions are 1280px by 720px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) or 960px by 720px (for 4:3 aspect ratio).
> Quality level hd1080: Player height is 1080px, and player dimensions are 1920px by 1080px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) or 1440px by 1080px (for 4:3 aspect ratio).
> Quality level highres: Player height is greater than 1080px, which means that the player's aspect ratio is greater than 1920px by 1080px.
> ```

There is a possibility that you may be playing a video in a player which doesn't meet the above expectations.Please refer [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_quality)(under heading **Playback quality**) for more info.